# one javascript to call another each with a set of command line arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files: 
server_sync.js and fetchServer.js

I run them such as:

```
node server_sync.js --server1 <hostname> --server2 <hostname2>
node fetchServer.js --server <hostname>
```

server_sync.js calls fetchServer.js's fetch() method, and I need fetchServer.js to work on its own with its set of parameters.

right now when i run fetchServer.js it's working fine, but when I run it from server_sync.js i'm getting an error:

```
unknown option --server1
```

i'm using the commander module

Comment: Please add relevant code - how do you call `fetchServer.js` from `server_sync`?